# Implementing a builder pattern for generating test cases in haskell

Tags: haskell, code-generation

I need to generate cucumber test cases for an application written in Java.

A test case would look like:

```
Scenario My great test
    Given the following input
        """
            Code snippet of a DSL
        """
    And the following data
        | name | type    | value |
        |    a | Boolean |  true |
        |    b | Integer |     5 |
    When I run the evaluation
    Then the result should be "Yay!"
```

I have created data types that resemble this structure as syntax tree as well as a "backend" which will take the syntax tree and create the test case string.

The data types look like:

```
data TestCase = Scenario String DslStatement DataStatement ResultStatement

data DslStatement = Dsl [TopLevelStatement]

data TopLevelStatement =
    StatementTypeA String
  | StatementTypeB String
  | StatementTypeC String SubStatementTypeA [SubStatementTypeB]
  | StatementTypeD String [String]

...
```

and so forth.

Now I want to generate lots and lots of these data structures using different values and types and stuff.

I could write functions that take the necessary parameters and create a syntax tree with the values from the parameters inserted at the locations they should appear. However, as the DSL contained in the test case is subject to change all the time (it is developed incrementally), I would have to change all the functions creating the different test case types all the time, which is tedious. Also, the test cases can be based on a standard syntax tree that is modified only at a handful of places for the majority of test cases.

My idea now is to create functions more or less similar to what would be a builder pattern with a fluent interface in Java. Starting with a standard syntax tree, I create functions that modify that and return the resulting tree to be further modified like this:

```
withName :: String -> TestCase -> TestCase
withName name (Scenario _ dsl data result) = Scenario name dsl data result

withResult :: ResultStatement -> TestCase -> TestCase
withResult result (Scenario name dsl data _) = Scenario name dsl data result

...
```

Then I should be able to write something like this:

```
withName "My Test Case" . withResult (Result "Yay!") $ createStandardTestCase
```

and as soon as the dsl changes only have to modify the builder functions and the backend in order to adapt my test cases.

Is this a possible/valid approach to the problem? 
Any better ideas for creating such syntax trees?

Thx!

--Mathias.

Comment: I wrote a post a while back about a fluent interface to builders [in this post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/02/you-could-have-invented-comonads.html).  Is that close to what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The fluent interface pattern is called `Endo` in Haskell. It's a `Monoid`, so you can gain some efficiency using `mconcat`, though I rarely see `Endo` used in practice since it isn't a huge gain.

One challenge you'll face with such a definition is the need for default everythings, after all `withName "My Test Case"` will need to be a valid `TestCase` all by itself. This may mean that many of your types will be `Maybe`s or it might just mean you want careful definitions of your types. This might be tied in to your notion of a standard syntax tree.

The fully-powered method for creating such an extensible AST is to use the [*Data types a la carte*](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) techniques. In short, you define a generic "sum" type operator then build functions which operate on some sum of components of your recursive type. By having clever defaults, you can omit many, many boilerplate definitions and allow for extensibility.

Such techniques might be useful for your types.

Finally, it's tough to talk about nested data types like this without tossing out a suggestion to look at lenses either through [`Control.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) (every conceivable battery included) or [`fc-labels`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels) (simpler). These let your formulate deep inspections into your trees which can be used bidirectionally, to both view and build update `Endo`s. They also have clever generic principles such as being able to "focus" on multiple locations in your tree simultaneously (these are the `Fold`s and `Traversal`s in `Control.Lens`).